# Installing pymedia on OSX

Tags: macos, python, troubleshooting

Trying to install the most recent version of [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/) available at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymedia/files/pymedia/pymedia-1.3.7.3/).

```
python setup.py install
```

I get the error:

```
In file included from sound/sound.cpp:33:
sound/audio_unix.h:29:10: fatal error: 'sys/soundcard.h' file not found
#include <sys/soundcard.h>
```

Possibly the core sound files have changed?

I'm running OSX 10.9 on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Getting the same problem - hope someone can help us out!

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/pymedia/mailman/pymedia-users/thread/A9A20DDD-2175-41CF-9741-C6746302DB4B@toneland.net/) link, it looks like pymedia hasn't been ported to OSX, which means we can't use it. That sucks!